# How to wrap multiple sql functions into a UDF in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with Spark 2.3.2.

On one column within my Dataframe I am performing many spark.sql.functions sequentually. How can I wrap this sequence of functions into a user-defined-function (UDF) to make it reusable?

Here is my example focusing on the one column "columnName". First I am creating my test data:

```scala
val testSchema = new StructType()
  .add("columnName", new StructType()
    .add("2020-11", LongType)
    .add("2020-12", LongType)
  )

val testRow = Seq(Row(Row(1L, 2L)))
val testRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(testRow)
val testDF = spark.createDataFrame(testRDD, testSchema)
testDF.printSchema()

/*
root
 |-- columnName: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2020-11: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2020-12: long (nullable = true)
*/

testDF.show(false)

/*
+----------+
|columnName|
+----------+
|[1, 2]    |
+----------+
*/
```

And here is the sequence of applied Spark SQL functions (just as an example):

```scala
val testResult = testDF
  .select(explode(split(regexp_replace(to_json(col("columnName")), "[\"{}]", ""), ",")).as("result"))
```

I am failing to create a UDF "myUDF", such that I can get the same result when calling

```scala
val testResultWithUDF = testDF.select(myUDF(col("columnName"))
```

This is what I "would like" to do:

```scala
def parseAndExplode(spalte: Column): Column = {
  explode(split(regexp_replace(to_json(spalte), "[\"{}]", ""), ",")
}
val myUDF = udf(parseAndExplode _)

testDF.withColumn("udf_result", myUDF(col("columnName"))).show(false)
```

but it is throwing an Exception:

```
Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported
```

Also tried with using a `Row` as input parameter but then again failed trying to apply built-in SQL functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use an udf here. `explode`, `split` and most other functions from [org.apache.spark.sql.functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html) return already an object of type [Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html).

```scala
def parseAndExplode(spalte: Column): Column = {
  explode(split(regexp_replace(to_json(spalte), "[\"{}]", ""), ","))
}

testDF.withColumn("udf_result",parseAndExplode('columnName)).show(false)
```

prints

```
+----------+----------+
|columnName|udf_result|
+----------+----------+
|[1, 2]    |2020-11:1 |
|[1, 2]    |2020-12:2 |
+----------+----------+
```